# c program compiles fine but closes unexpectly

Tags: c, function-pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

char *sum(char nn1[],char nn2[]){
    int i,j,s,max=0,c=0,reslen=0;
    max=(strlen(nn2)>strlen(nn1))?strlen(nn2):strlen(nn1);
    char *str=(char*)malloc(max+1);
    char n1[max],n2[max];
    char st[max+1];

    for(i=0;i<max;i++){
        n1[i]='0';n2[i]='0';
    }

    for(i=max-strlen(nn1),j=0;j<strlen(nn1);j++){
        n1[i]=nn1[j];
        i++;
    }

    for(i=max-strlen(nn2),j=0;j<strlen(nn2);j++){
        n2[i]=nn2[j];
        i++;
    }


    for(i=max-1;i>=0;i--){
        s=(n1[i]-'0')+(n2[i]-'0')+c;
        st[i+1]=s%10+'0';
        c=s/10;
    }

    if(c){
        reslen=max+1;
        st[0]='1';
    }else{
        reslen=max;
        for(i=0;i<=max;i++)
            st[i]=st[i+1];
        st[i]='\0';
    }

    for(i=0;i<reslen;i++){
        str[i]=st[i];
    }

    if(strlen(str)!=reslen){
        str[reslen]='\0';
    }


    return str;

}

int main()
{
    unsigned int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char *s0=sum("0","0");
    char *a[n];
    a[n]=malloc(10000);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%s",a[i]);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        s0=sum(s0,a[i]);

    printf("%s",s0);

    return 0;
}
```

The above program closes unexpectly. I run this program in gcc, first scan no. of input and then scan numbers in string format and then perform sum function. Please fix error.

The sum function working fine without scanf() in main function, but it closes when using it with scanf().

Comment: I couldn't spot any function pointers.

Comment: char *s0=sum("0","0");

Comment: This is not a function pointer. This is a variable of type *pointer to char* being assigned result of the sum() function, also of type *pointer to char*.

Comment: can anyone solve error ?

Comment: @UchihaLucky: We are neither a coding nor a debugging or tutoring service. Read [ask] and maybe you want to recap your course material - better get a good C book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is not allocated properly
You should allocate it in the loop prior to taking input in it with scanf

```
a[n]=malloc(10000);// remove this statement, a[n] is out of bound too

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a[i] = malloc(10000); // allocate inside loop
    scanf("%s",a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanx bro, program running fine, I have little knowledge in pointers, so can u suggest me how to learn pointers ?

Comment: For good programming practice, and developing good habits: you should call free() on each member of your array of pointers before exiting main.  also, `char *a[n];`is far from being available on all compilers, consider using `malloc` for allocating `a` itself.